# Inheritance/Polymporphism for mathematical function calculators

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, integration

I am writing C# code in a Windows Form which is using Simpson's Rule to calculate the mathematical integral of a particular function.

My program is complete, however I would like to make it rather more dynamic and add an extra functionality to my form1.cs[design]. I would like to use inheritance and polymorphism to extend my class to take in different functions for integrations.

This will be a very useful functionality in my form but I cannot find anything relevant. Does anyone know how I can add this functionality to my existing calculator code?

This is how I currently define the function I want to integrate using the Simpson's rule.

```
public virtual double funct(double x)
{
    return 2 / (1 + 4*(x * x));
}
```

When I change the function from  there, my form1.cs[design] gives me right results.......However I want to be able to choose different functions (any function for integration) from my form.cs[design]

Comment: Very hard to help if you don't show any relevant code...

Comment: Hard to tell what you want. "I want to be able to choose different functions" sounds like a (small) set of functions to choose from. The corresponding GUI element would be a list box. You can use a delegate as suggested below, which is a fancy function pointer, or indeed inheritance and polymorphism, especially if you want to do have more features and information attached to your function (IsMonotonic, ToString etc.).

Comment: @PeterSchneider Even in case of needing more information/features added to the function, inheritance is not, IMHO, the solution to this problem. I'd solve that with a wrapper class around `Func<double, double>` decorating it with the needed properties.

Comment: @InBetween TMTOWTDI. It's just that classically inheritance solves problems more flexibly and arguably more elegantly which before OO were solved with function pointers (call code which was unknown when the caller was written).

Comment: When I say choose different functions I mean I want to be able to type any mathematical function, which then will be used in the rest of my code to make the calculation. Currently that function is hard coded as mention above, but I want to be able to define any function in my form1, that could be x^2, 1/x, 1/x^2/ ax^2+bx+c, any mathematical expression.

Comment: See my answer (last paragraph). That is an altogether different problem and not easy to solve. You either have to create a *parser* or some mathematical expression building tool to use jointly with [System.Linq.Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) but it is no trivial task.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this through polyphormism.

You should just store the function as a variable:

```
Func<double, double> function; //represents a method that takes one double argument and returns a double
```

Assigning your example to `function` is pretty straightforward:

```
function = (double x) => 2 / (1 + 4 * (x * x));
```

And I'd create an interface `IFunctionIntegrator` like so:

```
public interface IFunctionIntegrator
{
     double Integrate(Func<double, double> function, double lowerLimit, double upperLimit);
}
```

Now you can easily decouple your `Form` implementation from your integration logic by injecting an `IFunctionIntegrator` in the constructor. *Allways* try to decouple as much as possible your UI form your application logic, it will save you many headaches in the future.

```
public partial class MyForm: Form
{  
     IFunctionIntegrator integrator;

     public MyForm() {...}
     public MyForm(IFunctionIntegrator integrator)
         :this()
     {
          this.integrator = integrator;
     }

     public double IntegrateFunction(Func<double, double> function, double lowerLimit, double upperLimit)
     {
         return this.integrator.Integrate(function, lowerLimit, upperLimit);
     }
}
```

And move your integration logic to a concrete implementation of `IFunctionIntegrator`:

```
public class SimpsonRuleFunctionIntegrator: IFunctionIntegrator
{
     public double Integrate(Func<double, double> function, double lowerLimit, double upperLimit)
     {
        //Simpson integration implementation here.
     }
}
```

Advantages of this approach? You don't only get flexibility choosing "any" function, you also get the flexibility of choosing any definite integration algorithm without having to change any code; you just need to add new implementations of `IFunctionIntegrator`.

```
public TrapezoidalRuleFunctionIntegrator: IFunctionIntegrator {...}
public RectangleRuleFunctionIntegrator: IFunctionIntegrator {...}
```

How you are going to implement choosing a *valid* function in your `Form` is another matter. Will these be built in functions? Otherwise you'll need to implement a mathematical [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) or an expression builder to validate and interpret the submitted function and thats an altogether different ballgame.